# Text/Image button in Safari not clicking

Tags: javascript, html, css, macos, safari

I've been searching around the apple forums and did a search here but I can't seem to find a solution.

I have a button which has text in it.
The button is a 'sliding doors' image button.
The button has a javascript event listener.
When the user clicks the text in the button the button does not function, however when the user clicks the image area of the button it does work.

Any idea how to fix this?

HTML

```
<div class="buttonWrapper listener">
    <div class="button">
        <div class="buttonText">Next</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.buttonWrapper{
    position: relative;
    z-index: 3;
    width:100%;
    max-width: 477px;
    height:152px;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background-color: green;
}
.button{
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    width:100%;
    max-width: 477px;
    height:304px;
    background-color:red;
}
.button:hover{
    opacity:0.7;
}
.button:active{
    top:-152px;
}
.buttonClicked{
    top:-152px;
}
.buttonText{
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    width: 100%;
    height:304px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: #fff;
    line-height: 152px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

I've put together a JSFiddle to show the issue.

```
http://jsfiddle.net/xv5of614/4/
```

On OSX Safari click the text, nothing happens.
Then click the read button area, an alert is triggered.

I should also add that this also happens if using an a href in place of the listener.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding `pointer-events: none;` to your .buttonText selector:

```
.buttonText{
    pointer-events: none;
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    width: 100%;
    height:304px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: #fff;
    line-height: 152px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xv5of614/5/

MDN Documentation for pointer events: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events

Comment: I can see it works in the fiddle but not in my code! I need to pull it apart and see where the conflicts are.

Answer (score 0):

**Untested thought:**

Move the event listener to the button text, so:

```
$('.buttonText').click(function(e){
    alert('clicked');
});
```

Since the text inside the button sits on top of everything else, make that's the clickable item.

Hope that helps.